# Extract the private and public key from the UTC file

Tags: go-ethereum, private-key, keystore, public-key

When I create a new account using Geth, it creates a UTC file corresponding to the account. All I know is that the UTC file consists of an encrypted private key.

How can I decrypt this? How can I extract its corresponding public key?

Detailed steps would be great.

Comment: If you rememer the passphrase the file was encrypted with, you coud use [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info) for that.

Comment: I know that. But I prefer doing it without any 3rd party application. Any help on that?